How do you replicate the spring boot cli jar -cp command with spring 3
Spring 3 dropped support for a large portion of the spring-boot-cli functionality, specifically, the following command:
spring jar newjar.jar -cp $CLASSPATH Main.groovy AnotherClass.groovy ...

According to this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-cli/issues/180, there is no replacement.  However, we still need that functionality, which is essentially packaging some java jars with some groovy classes and creating a runnable spring boot jar with them.  Is there another way of going about this to get the same result?
For our environment, we have a docker container that contains a lib directory locally with all the necessary jars that we would want included in our classpath, along with the groovy files that are not yet in a jar.  Our current implementation starts up the app via the following, but it can also be manipulated however it must:
java -Xms256m -Xmx2g ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar newjar.jar 2>&1 &

Note: we don't want to force a pre-packaged jar.  The point of the current architecture is to be able to make quick modifications to the groovy files and do a quick restart of the app, rather than having to go through a build process and redeployment. With that being said, maven is installed inside of the container if there's a route to go using that, but it would have to be in offline mode.
Edit: add basic example
this quick and dumb example should illustrate the situation.  For this example app, it will literally just run a Groovy script that autowires a Spring ConfigurationProperties file from a java jar and prints out the property in it.
build a jar with this class
package com.test;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties("com.test")
public class TestConfigurationProperties {

    private String testAttr;

    public String getTestAttr() {
        return testAttr;
    }

    public void setTestAttr(String testAttr) {
        this.testAttr = testAttr;
    }
}

The only dependency needed is:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

extending from spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.18.  That jar, and the dependencies brought in from maven, get copied to a local /lib directory.
Now also create a groovy script that is the main:
package com.test.groovy;

import com.test.TestConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TestConfigurationProperties.class)
public class TestMain implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private TestConfigurationProperties testConfigurationProperties;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestMain.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println(testConfigurationProperties.getTestAttr());
    }
}

and an application.yml:
com:
  test:
    test-attr: "attr"

when building the docker, we unpack spring-boot-cli:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <!--  Add SPRING BOOT CLI-->
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-spring-boot-cli</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>spring-boot-cli</artifactId>
                                    <version>2.7.18</version>
                                    <classifier>bin</classifier>
                                    <type>tar.gz</type>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/springbootcli</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
               </executions>
          <plugin

now finally a bash script to actually do stuff:
# just adding the jars in the lib directory and current directory to classpath
CLASSPATH=.:/lib:${CLASSPATH}

# combine jar and groovy files
spring jar test-app.jar --classpath=$CLASSPATH TestMain.groovy

# run the jar
java -Xms256m -Xmx2g ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar test-app.jar

Here is the result of the example (just printing out the attribute):
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.18)

[main] INFO org.springframework.boot.cli.archive.PackagedSpringApplicationLauncher - Starting PackagedSpringApplicationLauncher using Java 17.0.12 on 535c532df539 with PID
84 (/opt/groovy/test-app.jar started by root in /opt/groovy)
[main] INFO org.springframework.boot.cli.archive.PackagedSpringApplicationLauncher - The following 1 profile is active: "secure"
[main] INFO org.springframework.boot.cli.archive.PackagedSpringApplicationLauncher - Started PackagedSpringApplicationLauncher in 0.994 seconds (JVM running for 1.252)
attr

this will work with spring-boot-cli... but spring jar test-app.jar no longer exists with spring 3.3.3.  So we need to have that same functionality, but without the spring jar command.

Have you tried adding -cp Main.groovy ... to the starting call? I'd have suggested/asked if you have tried to add the groovy files yourself to the jar, but you ruled that out in the last paragraph - but then again isn't that what spring jar did? It would really help if you would provide a [mre] to see what result you are actually after.

to which command? because it's straight up gone on the spring command.  I think one of this issues is that there's nothing compiling the groovy files? maybe? but in regards to adding the files to the jar, I'm going to admit, I could have just done that wrong.  Or going into the wrong jar... essentially I was using jar uf, but it would either empty the jar and put that 1 file in, or put that file in and java jar not find the class.  As for the example... I'm not sure what to include? it's literally a directory of jars and groovy files and using that spring command to point to them

Maybe copy all the jars and the groovy files into the image and run java -cp .:lib groovy.ui.GroovyMain Main.groovy? But without some solid example it's hard (for me) to tell, what you are after; whether spring jar was some elaborate puzzle piece or it just helped to do a weird thing.

oooookay, I added an example that hopefully shows the issue.  Note the command you just recommended leads to the script not finding the autowired stuff (I assume it didn't get packaged as a spring boot app)

I didn't work with the spring CLI command so I didn't test this, but you probably should try the maven plugin to run the spring application, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/maven-plugin/run.html. It will not be a drop-in replacement, but hopefully a good starting point.

I've tried a good amount of things when doing this, but I get a ClassNotFoundException when pointing to a groovy script for the mainClass, i.e. adding this to the plugin configuration: <mainClass>package.Main</mainClass> (class in file Main.groovy).  adding <additionalClasspathElement>path/to/Main.groovy</additionalClasspathElement> didn't seem to help. I tried using the gmavenplus-plugin to compile java and groovy together, but that had a lot of issues referring to jars in a local directory
